# Should I Set docker image version in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Imagine I have `docker-compose.yml` for adding `mongo` as a container, is it a good thing to set verion in front of image name or let it to be the latest by default?

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Actually what is the pros and cons for application in development and production realeses?

`image: mongo:4.0` VS `image: mongo`

Comment: In production, you should always version pin your dependencies / images. Otherwise, you have undefined behaviour. In development, you can use latest, and when you want to deploy to prod, you use the version that's currently latest that you have in dev and pin it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including a version number as you've done is good practice.  I'd generally use a major-only image tag (`mongo:4`) or a major+minor tag (`mongo:4.4`) but not a super-specific version (`mongo:4.4.10`) unless you have automation to update it routinely.

Generally the Docker Hub images get rebuilt fairly routinely; but, within a given patch line, only the most-recent versions get patches.  Say the `debian:focal` base image gets a security update.  As of this writing, the `mongo` image has `4`, `4.4`, and `4.4.10` tags, so all of those get rebuilt, but *e.g.* `4.4.9` won't.  So using a too-specific version could mean you don't get important updates.

Conversely, using `latest` means you just don't care what version you have.  Your question mentions `mongo:4.0` but `mongo:latest` is currently version 5.0.5; are there compatibility issues with that major-version upgrade?

The key rules here are:

1. If you already have some `image:tag` locally, launching a container will not pull it again, even if it's updated in the repository.
2. Minor-version tags like `mongo:4.4` will continue to get updates as long as they are supported, but you may need to `docker-compose pull` to get updates.
3. Patch-version tags like `mongo:4.4.9` will stop getting updates as soon as there's a newer patch version, even if you `docker pull mongo:4.4.9`.
4. Using a floating tag like `...:latest` or a minor-version tag could mean different systems get different builds of the image, depending on what they have locally.  (Your coworker could have a different `mongo:latest` than you; this is a bigger problem in cluster environments like Kubernetes.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good thing to put version in front of the image name, you can manage them more easily, but you have to be careful to pass the update regularly to avoid loopholes.

Comment: do you mind elaborating exactly what you mean? for instance, two example compose.yml files?